# One cell low in e-bike battery - safe to use?

Tags: batteries

I have a 13s5p e-bike battery pack. 5 years old, around 100-120 full cycles, measured capacity 14.7 Ah (nominal: 16 Ah).

After winter storage, I took it for a ride and the BMS disconnected earlier than expected. Upon disassembly, measuring the cell groups using the balance leads, 12 were nicely aligned at 3.62-3.63 V, but group #6 was at 3.25 V (so it probably went under 3 V during load).

There is no visible damage or problem. I charged the suspect group to align with the others. It holds charge after 3 days.

Everything is spot welded, it's not feasible to swap the suspect group only. Would you fully charge the pack and keep using the battery, or there's clearly an internal issue in one group and it's unsafe?

Comment: Probably that cell has slightly lower capacity. I would charge all cells to 100 % SOC and monitor said cell. Ideally, your BMS should do this for you. Unless you can live with lower capacity, you have no other option but to replace the cell.

Comment: Thanks. After fully charging, the voltage difference stayed (4.2V for 12 groups, 4.0V for the low cell). It looks like there was something draining that particular group during the six months of storage - maybe the cheap Daly BMS. I'll follow up.

Comment: I’d manually CC-CV charge that offending cell to 4.2 V. Feel if it’s getting hot.

Comment: It would have taken forever to top-charge that group through the tiny balance lead (or would have needed to set cahrger voltage above safe 4.2V to compensate for the drop). I discharged the battery, charged to equalize to 3.6V, then charged the whole pack. All groups are balanced. It seems that for whatever reason group 6 lost some charge on its own (BMS?). Thanks again for your answers, problem solved